# Xamarin Android - I need to copy all the *.jpg files from my internal application storage to Documents or Downloads

Tags: android, xamarin, copy

Xamarin Android 11 and higher -  I need to copy all the *.jpg files programmatically from my internal application storage to Documents or Downloads so that I can retrieve them if a user is having issues.  Please give me sample code that I can plug into my application's code.  Thank you in advance.

It seems impossible find any sample code that works without errors.  When someone says do it like this or like that, it just doesn't work.  Please I need sample code.

Comment: You need to request permissions from the user to those two folders or ask for permissions to manage all files in external storage. Then you can copy over the files. Which permissions did you request?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.